# AWS CloudFormation CodePipeline: Could not fetch the contents of the repository from GitHub

Tags: github, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, github-webhook

I'm attempting to setup an AWS CloudFormation configuration using CodePipeline and GitHub.

I've failed both at my own example project and the tutorial: [Create a GitHub Pipeline with AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-cloudformation-github.html).

All resources are created, but in CodePipeline I continuously get the following error during the initial "Source" stage.

`Could not fetch the contents of the repository from GitHub.`

See image below:

[image: CodePipeline with Github failing with "Could not fetch the contents of the repository from Github."]

Note that this is not a permissions error. It's something else that does not exist on Google until now.

GitHub can be configured to work if I stop using CloudFormation and create a CodePipeline through the console, but for my purposes, I need to use CloudFormation. Need to stick to a template.

Here is the template from the CloudFormation template copied from the tutorial:

```
Parameters:
  BranchName:
    Description: GitHub branch name
    Type: String
    Default: master
  RepositoryName:
    Description: GitHub repository name
    Type: String
    Default: test
  GitHubOwner:
    Type: String
  GitHubSecret:
    Type: String
    NoEcho: true
  GitHubOAuthToken:
    Type: String
    NoEcho: true
  ApplicationName:
    Description: CodeDeploy application name
    Type: String
    Default: DemoApplication
  BetaFleet:
    Description: Fleet configured in CodeDeploy
    Type: String
    Default: DemoFleet
Resources:
  CodePipelineArtifactStoreBucket:
    Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
  CodePipelineArtifactStoreBucketPolicy:
    Type: "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy"
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref CodePipelineArtifactStoreBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Sid: DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads
            Effect: Deny
            Principal: "*"
            Action: "s3:PutObject"
            Resource: !Join
              - ""
              - - !GetAtt
                  - CodePipelineArtifactStoreBucket
                  - Arn
                - /*
            Condition:
              StringNotEquals:
                "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "aws:kms"
          - Sid: DenyInsecureConnections
            Effect: Deny
            Principal: "*"
            Action: "s3:*"
            Resource: !Join
              - ""
              - - !GetAtt
                  - CodePipelineArtifactStoreBucket
                  - Arn
                - /*
            Condition:
              Bool:
                "aws:SecureTransport": false
  AppPipelineWebhook:
    Type: "AWS::CodePipeline::Webhook"
    Properties:
      Authentication: GITHUB_HMAC
      AuthenticationConfiguration:
        SecretToken: !Ref GitHubSecret
      Filters:
        - JsonPath: $.ref
          MatchEquals: "refs/heads/{Branch}"
      TargetPipeline: !Ref AppPipeline
      TargetAction: SourceAction
      Name: AppPipelineWebhook
      TargetPipelineVersion: !GetAtt
        - AppPipeline
        - Version
      RegisterWithThirdParty: true
  AppPipeline:
    Type: "AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline"
    Properties:
      Name: github-events-pipeline
      RoleArn: !GetAtt
        - CodePipelineServiceRole
        - Arn
      Stages:
        - Name: Source
          Actions:
            - Name: SourceAction
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Source
                Owner: ThirdParty
                Version: 1
                Provider: GitHub
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: SourceOutput
              Configuration:
                Owner: !Ref GitHubOwner
                Repo: !Ref RepositoryName
                Branch: !Ref BranchName
                OAuthToken: !Ref GitHubOAuthToken
                PollForSourceChanges: false
              RunOrder: 1
        - Name: Beta
          Actions:
            - Name: BetaAction
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: SourceOutput
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Deploy
                Owner: AWS
                Version: 1
                Provider: CodeDeploy
              Configuration:
                ApplicationName: !Ref ApplicationName
                DeploymentGroupName: !Ref BetaFleet
              RunOrder: 1
      ArtifactStore:
        Type: S3
        Location: !Ref CodePipelineArtifactStoreBucket
  CodePipelineServiceRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - codepipeline.amazonaws.com
            Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: AWS-CodePipeline-Service-3
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "codecommit:CancelUploadArchive"
                  - "codecommit:GetBranch"
                  - "codecommit:GetCommit"
                  - "codecommit:GetUploadArchiveStatus"
                  - "codecommit:UploadArchive"
                Resource: "*"
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "codedeploy:CreateDeployment"
                  - "codedeploy:GetApplicationRevision"
                  - "codedeploy:GetDeployment"
                  - "codedeploy:GetDeploymentConfig"
                  - "codedeploy:RegisterApplicationRevision"
                Resource: "*"
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "codebuild:BatchGetBuilds"
                  - "codebuild:StartBuild"
                Resource: "*"
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "devicefarm:ListProjects"
                  - "devicefarm:ListDevicePools"
                  - "devicefarm:GetRun"
                  - "devicefarm:GetUpload"
                  - "devicefarm:CreateUpload"
                  - "devicefarm:ScheduleRun"
                Resource: "*"
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "lambda:InvokeFunction"
                  - "lambda:ListFunctions"
                Resource: "*"
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "iam:PassRole"
                Resource: "*"
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "elasticbeanstalk:*"
                  - "ec2:*"
                  - "elasticloadbalancing:*"
                  - "autoscaling:*"
                  - "cloudwatch:*"
                  - "s3:*"
                  - "sns:*"
                  - "cloudformation:*"
                  - "rds:*"
                  - "sqs:*"
                  - "ecs:*"
                Resource: "*"
```

I've have taken the following steps:

- provided Github Organization, Repo & Branch
- setup a personal access token on GitHub and supplied it to the template `GitHubOAuthToken` parameter with access to `repo:all` & `admin:repo_hook`
- setup a random string and provided it to the `GitHubSecret`
- tried not including a `GitHubSecret` as in many other examples
- verified that AWS CodePipeline for my region is listed in Github Applications under "Authorized OAuth Applications"

In attempts to start from a clear slate, I've also done the following:

- cleared all GitHub webhooks before starting `aws codepipeline list-webhooks` & `aws codepipeline delete-webhook --name`
- added a new personal access token
- tried multiple repos & branches

Any ideas how I can get GitHub to work with CloudFormation & CodePipeline?

Answer (score 17):

Found the solution. The Github organization name is case sensitive.

Comment: silly mistake, Thank you so much for answering your question

Comment: Thank you kindly, you just saved me hours of pain and frustration :)

Comment: Same here! Saved me hours :-)

Comment: Also note, the repo field is case sensitive too. That had me confused for longer than I would have like :)